# Can I use self-levelling compound over old carpet adhesive?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, self-leveling-concrete

Can I use self-levelling compound over old carpet adhesive? I've ripped up the current carpets and found a couple of strips of very old carpet glue that are proving a NIGHTMARE to remove from the concrete. Do I have to? I'm going to use a primer, and then go about 4mm with the self leveller, and then put floating floorboards over the top of that. My real question is if the old glue will mess with the levelling compound in any way and cause me problems later. And if I do try remove, what should I use?[image]

Comment: Self levelling compound would need to be spread over the whole floor to make it level with the strips.  If the floor is not flat( dips/humps) then go for it.  If the floor is flat, then removing those strips might be better.  What you are going to put on the floor after and what you are using to remove the glue(edit into question) will get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If that glue is totally dry and crusty then I would opt for a good mask and a belt sander.

If it's sticky then try some brake cleaner and good ventilation.

Comment: Yes, a belt sander and some heavy grit belts would get this done in a very short time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but I personally wouldn’t. I had the situation as you and I chose to remove the glue as it might have contained asbestos. I suggest you rent a floor scarifier which will properly and effortless remove any protuberance - ask the supplier for an accessory for removing glue. For me (amateur), it took a day to remove the complete old leveling compound up to the concrete for 50sqm.

If you do elect not to do that, make sure you liberally use a quality primer before laying the mass